# Is using a friend's wand better than using a stranger's wand?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

We all know that wands tend to be picky depending on the flexibility of the wood, thus if the wand is used not by their owner, the spells tend to be weaker. But does the potency of spells differ? If for example, Harry used Hermione's wand, compared to if Harry used Draco's wand? Does that bond of friendship make the wand more powerful for a best friend than it is to a complete stranger or enemy?

Comment: [kaboom](https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/240/apple/118/shocked-face-with-exploding-head_1f92f.png)

Comment: Harry did use Draco's wand, but he won it from him. Probably a better comparison is Hermione using Bellatrix's, and Harry using Ron's (Both of which are described in Hallows).

Comment: That title just... sounds wrong.

Comment: The title of this question could make the multiverse implode.

Comment: deathly hallows should have some answers

Answer (score 11):

## Yes, it does seem to be better to use a friend’s wand.

Harry uses a stranger’s wand when he uses the wand Ron got from a Snatcher. The Snatcher would basically be a stranger to Harry, since he wouldn’t know that Snatcher more than any of the others. They would have been “enemies”, but he wouldn’t have known the Snatcher well enough to have any *personal* enmity.

> “Sorry – *reducio*.’
>
> The spider did not shrink. Harry looked down at the blackthorn wand. Every minor spell he had cast with it so far that day had seemed less powerful than those he had produced with his phoenix wand. The new one felt intrusively unfamiliar, like having somebody else’s hand sewn to the end of his arm.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 20 (Xenophilius Lovegood)*</sup></sub>

Before that, he had been borrowing Hermione’s wand, which was working fairly well for him. He hadn’t been complaining as much while he was using hers, and casting spells hadn’t been a problem like it had been with the Snatcher’s wand.

He said using Draco’s wand, a wand he’d won from its owner, worked “at least as well as Hermione’s”. Therefore, Hermione’s wand worked about as well as a wand he’d won from its owner.

> “Harry looked down at the hawthorn wand that had once belonged to Draco Malfoy. He had been surprised, but pleased, to discover that it worked for him at least as well as Hermione’s had done.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 26 (Gringotts)*</sup></sub>

## Conversely, using an enemy’s wand is likely worse.

Hermione tried using Bellatrix’s wand, which she stole from its rightful owner, and it didn’t work very well for her. (Serves her right! :P)

> “Hermione looked frightened that the wand might sting or bite her as she picked it up.
>
> ‘I hate this thing,’ she said in a low voice. ‘I really hate it. It feels all wrong, it doesn’t work properly for me … it’s like a bit of *her*.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 26 (Gringotts)*</sup></sub>

It’s unclear how much of the problem is psychological, but both she and Harry react badly to being around the wand. Harry, however, only reacts after being reminded what had been done with the wand, so his reaction seemed more psychological.

> “But that’s my point!’ said Hermione. ‘This is the wand that tortured Neville’s mum and dad, and who knows how many other people? This is the wand that killed Sirius!’
>
> Harry had not thought of that: he looked down at the wand and was visited by a brutal urge to snap it, to slice it in half with Gryffindor’s sword, which was propped against the wall beside him.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 26 (Gringotts)*</sup></sub>

Whatever the cause though, using it didn’t work well for Hermione.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @JohnP Harry had won Draco's wand but I think the evidence does suggest that they do work better because Harry finds Hermione's wand fine but Hermione does not find Bellatrix's wand very nice to use. However, it never actually says in any canon whether this is correct so don't take my word for it.